# The number of surjection from n elemental set to n-1 elemental set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How much is count of surjection from $n$ elemental to $n-1$ elemental set ?

I have start that:

$A=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$

$B=\{y_1, y_2,...,y_n-1\}$

And number of surjection is $(n-1)^n$ ?

But I dont know how is next step.

Answer (score 2):

For a surjection, exactly one $y_k$ must be hit twice, i.e., exactly two of the $x_i$ map to the same value. So we first pick one of $n\choose 2$ pairs from the $x_i$ and declare that they are the ones mapping to the same value. Now if we drop one element of the chosen pair, we are left with the task to find a bijection between two sets of cardinality $n-1$ each. There are $(n-1)!$ such bijections, hence the final answer is
$$ {n\choose 2}\cdot (n-1)! = \frac{n-1}{2}\cdot n!.$$

Comment: I think you are missing a factor $n-1$ for the element of $B$ that receives the pair.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $(n-1)^n$ is the total number of functions from $A$ to $B$, but not all of them are surjections.  To have a surjection, one element in $B$ must be the image of two elements in $A$ and all the other elements in $B$ must be the image of exactly one element in $A$.  One way to count the surjections is to count the ways to pick the element of $B$ that is the image of two elements of A, count the ways to pick the two elements in $A$ that go to that element, then count the ways to make a bijection among the rest of the elements.